# Error as '`' (backquotes) not allowed in javascript (ecma5)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

```js
var now = new Date();

var year = now.getUTCFullYear();
var month = now.getUTCMonth() + 1;
var day = now.getUTCDate();
var hours = now.getUTCHours();
var minutes = now.getUTCMinutes();
var seconds = now.getUTCSeconds();
var milliseconds = now.getUTCMilliseconds();
var test = `${year}-${month}-${day} ${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
console.log(test);
```

Are backquotes not allowed in javascript (`) ?
I am trying in ecma5 but getting error as mentioned above.

And also, can we match regular expression for above mentioned date-time format ?

Comment: WHAT is giving you that error? It is part of ECMAScript 6, not 5.

Comment: To answer your question, yes template literals ("backquotes") are part of ES2015/ES6.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#browser_compatibility

Comment: But not in EcmaScript5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, the lastest version of JS is EcmaScript6, and many references online use EcmaScript13 specs.

Backticks are not allowed in Ecmascript 5, they were added to serve easier access to multi-lined strings in EcmaScript6.

You can use the + sign:

```
let a = year+'-'+month+'-'+day+' '+hours+':'+minutes+':'+seconds;
```

Comment: "*the lastest version of JS is EcmaScript6*" - nope. We're at [EcmaScript 13.0](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/) right now, and getting a new version every year.

Comment: Sorry, You're right we're way over ES6

Comment: thanks for mentioning about these version changes.